# How to authenticate Netlify identity with Go function

Tags: go, aws-lambda, netlify

In the documentation for Netlify functions they show with Node how to identify if a request is from a logged in user.

https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/#identity-and-functions

Looking through the Go structs for the context it doesn't appear that the user data is available in Go. I must be missing something. How do I validate a user and get their info from the JWT with Go Lamda functions in Netlify?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-identity-and-go-functions/17810

```js
type Bearer struct {
    Identity *Identity `json:"identity"`
    User     *User     `json:"user"`
    SiteUrl  string    `json:"site_url"`
    Alg      string    `json:"alg"`
}

type Identity struct {
    URL   string `json:"url"`
    Token string `json:"token"`
}

type User struct {
    AppMetaData  *AppMetaData  `json:"app_metadata"`
    Email        string        `json:"email"`
    Exp          int           `json:"exp"`
    Sub          string        `json:"sub"`
    UserMetadata *UserMetadata `json:"user_metadata"`
}
type AppMetaData struct {
    Provider string `json:"provider"`
}
type UserMetadata struct {
    FullName string `json:"full_name"`
}

func AuthMiddleware(h *Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        lc, ok := lambdacontext.FromContext(r.Context())
        if !ok {
            err := errors.New("server error")
            h.logger.Errorf("error retrieving context %+v", r.Context())
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        bearer := lc.ClientContext.Custom["netlify"]
        raw, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(bearer)
        if err != nil {
            h.logger.Error(err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        data := Bearer{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(raw, &data)
        if err != nil {
            h.logger.Error(err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        if data.User == nil {
            err := errors.New("forbidden")
            h.logger.Errorf("Unauthenticated request bearer: %+v", bearer)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

There is also a blog: https://matthewkrump.com/2020-07-13-netlify-go-functions/ for more details